# How to write test case for executing except block at least once for a non-failing method in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, ubuntu, exception, code-coverage

I have created a python class as below -

```
class MyClass:
    mydict = {}
    error = None
    traceback = None
    message = None

    def create_log_message(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            error = kwars.get("error", self.error)
            traceback = kwargs.get("traceback", self.traceback)
            message = kwargs.get("message", self.message)
            self.mydict = {"error": error, "traceback": traceback, "message": message}
            return self.mydict
        except Exception as e:
            error = e
            traceback = tb.format_exc()
            message = kwargs.get("message", self.message)
            self.mydict = {"error": error, "traceback": traceback, "message": message}
            return self.mydict
```

Below is my test class -

```
import unittest import TestCase
import traceback as tb
import MyClass
class TestMyClass(TestCase):
    def test_success(self):                                       # Test in case of success
        inst = MyClass()
        mydict = inst.create_log_message(message="success")
        self.assertEqual(mydict["error"], None)
        self.assertEqual(mydict["traceback"], None)
        self.assertEqual(mydict["message"], "success")
 
    def test_failure(self):                                       # test in case of exception
        try:
            1/0
        except ArithmeticError as e:
            error = e
            traceback = tb.format_exc()
            inst = MyClass()
            mydict = inst.create_log_message(error=error, traceback=traceback, message="failure")
            self.assertEqual(mydict["error"], error)
            self.assertEqual(mydict["traceback"], traceback)
            self.assertEqual(mydict["message"], "failure")

    def test_no_args(self):                                       # test for no argument being passed
        inst = MyClass()
        mydict = inst.create_log_message()
        self.assertEqual(mydict["error"], None)
        self.assertEqual(mydict["traceback"], None)
        self.assertEqual(mydict["message"], None)

    def test_extra_args(self):                                    # test for any other argument
        inst = MyClass()
        mydict = inst.create_log_message(name="test")
        with self.assertRaises(KeyError):
            self.assertEqual(mydict["name"], "test")
        self.assertEqual(mydict["error"], None)
        self.assertEqual(mydict["traceback"], None)
        self.assertEqual(mydict["message"], None)
```

My problem is except block in MyClass is not getting called not even once, even if I pass no arguements, matching arguments or any other/extra arguments, hence code coverage is failing(not meeting 100%), how to execute the except block via test case at least once? I am using python3.8x/ubuntu20.04.

Any help in this regard will be really helpful :)

PS: Please forgive if I have missed any details as this is my first post on stack overflow.

Comment: I want to call except block at least once from my test case without making any changes to MyClass, how shall I write such a test case which can make sure that except block of MyClass gets executed at least once given MyClass can take any arbitrary kwargs and if none are passed then all the kwargs will be initialized to None and returned from try block itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The except block is not getting executed since you have mentioned default value as `None` inside try block in `MyClass` i.e `kwars.get("error", self.error)`.Just remove the default value and it will work.

```
class MyClass:
mydict = {}
error = None
traceback = None
message = None

def create_log_message(self, **kwargs):
    try:
        error = kwargs["error"]
        traceback = kwargs["traceback"]
        message = kwargs["message"]
        self.mydict = {"error": error, "traceback": traceback, "message": message}
        return self.mydict
    except Exception as e:
        error = e
        traceback = tb.format_exc()
        error = kwargs.get("error", self.error)
        traceback = kwargs.get("traceback", self.traceback)
        message = kwargs.get("message", self.message)
        self.mydict = {"error": error, "traceback": traceback, "message": message}
        return self.mydict
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test failing case, you might try unittest.mock. If you pass an exception to `side_effect` parameter of the mock, this exception will be raised.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

But first think about real case when this exception can occur and try to mock this case. If there is no way exception will be raised, there is no need in code handling it.

Comment: There's no need for Mock here, is there?

Answer (score 0):

First, do you really need that except clause?  What errors are you handling?  The code in your try block doesn't raise any exceptions, so there's no way to cause an exception. Rather than focus on how to test that code, I would simply remove it. You don't need it.